# ¿Como desinstalo Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, windows, windows10

Debido a problemas que tengo para probar `React Native`, estoy intentando desinstalar `Android Studio` desde `Windows 10`, sin embargo a pesar que usé la opción
*Desinstalar o cambiar un programa* del panel de control, Android Studio sigue instalado, y cuando regreso al panel de control Android Studio no existe.

¿Alguien me puede decir a que se debe esto? Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que ya fue desinstalado `Android Studio` desde `Panel de Control` pero ahora se deben eliminar manualmente algunos archivos y directorios.

ve a:

```
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\
```

que abrirá tu "perfil", ahí elimina el directorio `\.android` que es el principal, si deseas eliminar el directorio de proyectos elimina también `\AndroidStudioProjects`

Posteriormente ve a:

```
C:\Users\%APPDATA%\
```

ahí elimina el directorio `\.JetBrains`

Posteriormente ve a :

```
  C:\Users\%LOCALAPPDATA%\
```

y elimina el directorio `\Android`

Revisa este tutorial:

**[¿Cómo desinstalar por completo Android Studio de Windows 10?](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/android/como-desinstalar-por-completo-android-studio-de-windows-v10/828204631/)**

---

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar completamente Android Studio de Windows:

Paso 1: Ejecute el Android desinstalador de Studio

El primer paso es ejecutar el desinstalador. Abra Panel de control y debajo de Programas, seleccione Desinstalar un programa. Después de eso, haga clic en "Android Studio" y presione Desinstalar. Si tiene varias versiones, desinstálelas también.

Paso 2: Elimine los archivos Android Studio

Para eliminar cualquier resto de Android Archivos de configuración de Studio, en el Explorador de archivos, vaya a su carpeta de usuario (%USERPROFILE%) y elimine .Android, .AndroidStudio y cualquier directorio análogo con versiones al final, es decir, .AndroidStudio1.2, así como .gradle y .m2 si existen.

Luego vaya a %APPDATA% y elimine el directorio JetBrains.

Finalmente, vaya a C:\Program Files y elimine el directorio Android.

Paso 3: Eliminar SDK

Para eliminar cualquier resto del SDK, vaya a %LOCALAPPDATA% y elimine el directorio Android.

Paso 4: Eliminar Android Proyectos de estudio

Android Studio crea proyectos en una carpeta %USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects, que es posible que desee eliminar.